# Gnuplot is returning: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

Tags: c, plot, graph, gnuplot

I have a set of data from my weather station that I would like to use to some graphs:
Data:

```
2022-11-04 00:01:13|9.78|23.02|6.04
2022-11-05 00:01:13|7.97|22.63|6.95
2022-11-06 00:01:12|10.29|22.49|7.88
2022-11-07 00:01:11|9.88|24.58|7.20
2022-11-08 00:01:14|12.18|25.11|10.82
2022-11-09 00:01:15|10.53|25.85|9.09
2022-11-10 00:01:12|10.49|24.52|8.40
2022-11-11 00:01:09|13.90|23.97|9.74
2022-11-12 00:01:10|13.54|22.60|12.72
2022-11-13 00:01:11|9.20|22.89|8.59
2022-11-14 00:01:13|9.68|23.35|6.71
2022-11-15 00:01:13|8.75|22.80|5.57
2022-11-16 00:01:11|8.60|23.04|1.77
2022-11-17 00:01:12|6.36|22.73|-1.49
2022-11-18 00:01:12|5.31|22.55|-0.59
2022-11-19 00:01:13|1.72|21.98|-0.14
2022-11-20 00:01:14|-0.23|21.67|-1.83
2022-11-21 00:01:11|-0.04|22.10|-0.16
2022-11-22 00:01:11|2.09|22.22|-1.22
2022-11-23 00:01:13|4.85|22.31|1.57
2022-11-24 00:01:15|6.54|22.85|5.21
2022-11-25 00:01:11|6.84|23.22|4.72
2022-11-26 00:01:12|6.76|22.70|6.71
2022-11-27 00:01:13|6.66|22.94|5.18
2022-11-28 00:01:10|5.71|22.97|0.80
2022-11-29 00:01:10|4.54|22.21|3.08
2022-11-30 00:01:09|4.25|22.76|3.81
2022-12-01 00:01:13|3.09|22.55|1.72
2022-12-02 00:01:14|3.12|22.53|1.50
2022-12-03 00:01:10|2.16|22.26|-1.09
2022-12-04 00:01:14|2.96|23.30|-1.74
```

This is my gnuplot setup:

```
set datafile separator "|"
set xdata time
set style data lines
unset multiplot
set term png
set autoscale y
set autoscale x
set grid xtics
set grid ytics
set grid mxtics
set grid mytics
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set output "/srv/www/rasp/cputemp/tempMd.png"
plot '-' using 1:2 t 'Ude' w lines, \
'-' using 1:3 t 'Inde' w lines
```

Using the data from above is making gnuplot returning:

```
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

Using only one line eg. 1:2 or 1:3 works but combining in one set fails.

Tried many solutions, different delimiter, set multiplot, removing grids.

Comment: How are you feeding this data to the program?  Each time it sees `'-'` in the plot command it will try to read a new input stream, which means if you are piping the data as input you would need to send two copies.  Can you provide a filename instead?

Comment: I fixed the issue by saving data to a file and the have gnuplot read the data from that file.